# attach received mail in Contacts attachment

Tags: email, apex-email-service

We have status field on contact. Once status becomes active , we have to create a Partner user and send term and condition mail to Contact email address.  Once the Contact replied "accepted", then he can log in partner community .

In addition , I have to attach both emails in the contact activity history .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the rough design that I can think of for this

> 1) Create a trigger on contact
>   and if status field if active
>   create a partner User in inactive
>   mode
>    2) Write a workflow on contact
>   to mail
>   all necessary thing
>   with VF email
>   template
>   3)You can create task in the trigger or workflow to log as an activity
>   4)Write an Email Service
>   and once its accepted
>   take the User record
>   with that Email
>   and activate the User
>   5)You can again log an activity against the contact with the Email Id .

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mohith. I attach the email itself in activity history instead of creating task to log an activity.